# Query to select all subscribers who have received Email from specific DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Sorry in advance if the question is repeated, but i have a goal that i want to know  how many emails the subscribers from a specific DE received in last and each month.

I tried to use the sintax below, but the numbers of records that the SQL is get it is very different to the number of total sent;

The primary key in target De is Month and SubscriberKey to get the number each month send for subscribers

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
SELECT count(*) AS TotalSent, 
DATENAME(month, p.EventDate) as [MONTH],
row_number()over(partition by p.SubscriberKey ORDER BY P.EventDate DESC) AS row,
'XX' as [Business_Unit],
p.SubscriberKey as SubscriberKey
FROM _Sent p 
INNER JOIN [Clients_XX] B ON p.SubscriberKey = B.AccountID
WHERE p.EventDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -365, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
GROUP BY p.EventDate, p.SubscriberKey
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
)
x
WHERE x.row = 1
```

Comment: First thing the _sent data view only has 6mths worth of data, which would be Jan 23 to today

Comment: Yes, but this could occasionated this numbers so different?

Comment: try doing the group by on DATENAME(month, p.EventDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the ROW_NUMBER function, the issue's with your grouping as p.EventDate is a time stamp (down to the millisecond). You'll get one row returned in your query for the most recent send to each Subscriber, effectively.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS TotalSent, 
    DATENAME(month, p.EventDate) as [MONTH],
    'XX' as [Business_Unit],
    p.SubscriberKey as SubscriberKey
FROM
    _Sent p INNER JOIN
    [Clients_XX] B ON
        p.SubscriberKey = B.AccountID
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(month, p.EventDate),
    p.SubscriberKey
HAVING COUNT(1) > 0
```

As EazyE points out, your WHERE clause doesn't hurt, particularly, but it's redundant... you only have the last six months of data available in the _Sent data view, in any case.